# git push doesn't create/update remote branch, but updates remote directly

Tags: git

Recently, my local git has changed how it pushes branches to remote and I can't figure out why. Previously, I would create new branches with the command:

`git checkout -b feature_x origin/master`

Then, push the new branch to remote (in order to create a Pull Request):

`git push origin feature_x`

This worked fine up until last week, however, now when I run that last command, git pushes directly to remote without creating a branch (or allowing a PR to be created for that branch). I'm thinking I must have changed a setting without realizing it, to get to this situation, but I'm not sure which one. Does anyone have any idea what would cause this behavior and perhaps a way to go back to the old way of doing things?

Output from `git push origin feature_x`:

```
To https://github.com/[URL]
  2826f0c..66748dc  feature_x -> master
```

Config:

```
push.default=tracking
core.editor=vim
core.askpass=git-gui--askpass
branch.autosetupmerge=true
credential.helper=osxkeychain
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/[URL]
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.feature_x.remote=origin
branch.feature_x.merge=refs/heads/master
```

Comment: You try to push to github?

Comment: Yep, I'm pushing to Github

Comment: Please add the output of `git push origin feature_x` and `git config -l` to your question.

Comment: I posted the push result - the problem is that it doesn't create a new remote branch, so I want it to return `feature_x -> feature_x`. I also posted my config below it...

Comment: Yep, the push.default setting was the issue! I have no idea how I set that to 'tracking', but I'll be watching out for that in the future - Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can execute the following command to update the upstream

```
git push -u origin feature_x
```

After that it should start to work as usually

Answer (score 0):

Please don't mix up braches and repositories.

You have two different repositories. Your local one and a remote one at github.

You create a branch `feature_x` in your local repository and commit your changes on that local branch.

Later you try to push your local branch to the remote repository. The complete syntax is:

```
git push origin src:dst
```

This means push to a remote location named origin (which is probably configured as your github repository) and take the local branch `src` and name it `dst` at the remote repository.

You did not specify `:dst`, therefore some default will be used.

From your description you expected `feature_x:feature_x` but you got `feature_x:master`.

`git help push` says:

```
   The <dst> tells which ref on the remote side is updated with this push.
   Arbitrary expressions cannot be used here, an actual ref must be named. If git
   push [<repository>] without any <refspec> argument is set to update some ref
   at the destination with <src> with remote.<repository>.push configuration
   variable, :<dst> part can be omitted---such a push will update a ref that
   <src> normally updates without any <refspec> on the command line. Otherwise,
   missing :<dst> means to update the same ref as the <src>.
```

Thanks for your update.

`git branch -vv` should show, that your feature branch is tracking `origin/master`. This is fine so far. But then `push.default=tracking` says you want to push to the tracking branch as a default. -> This explains the `feature_x:master` behavior.

Maybe you want `push.default=current` or `push.default=simple`. (Since git 2.0 `simple` is also the default.)

Comment: Thanks! That does help - I realized that new branches I'm creating to track remotely are now being added to my config file, so each branch is now getting added with an example below. I believe the merge command is telling git to merge it directly into that branch rather than creating a new remote branch. Do you know which setting is doing this? I have push.default = trakcing and branch.autosetupmerge = true.
    [branch "test_branch_3"]
     remote = origin
     merge = refs/heads/zanzibar

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have any idea what would cause this behavior and perhaps a way to go back to the old way of doing things?

It looks like @michas, with the help of your config, already identified `push.default=tracking` as the problem.

As long as you're using git 2.37+, I would like to recommend, based on your expectations, however, that you use the following setup:

```
git config --global push.default simple
git config --global branch.autoSetupMerge simple
git config --global push.autoSetupRemote true
```

- `push.default=simple` will ensure that you only push "implicitly" to remote branches with the same name as your local branch name, and fail otherwise.
- `branch.autoSetupMerge=simple` will ensure that you only get tracking relationships on new branches when they are created from same-name remote branches.
- `push.autoSetupRemote=true` will ensure that when you push a new local branch to the remote, it automatically gets a tracking relationship (so `git pull` works, `git status` shows you how many local unpushed commits you have, etc), and it also makes `git push` just work on new branches - without needing to specify the remote, or the branch. For a new branch, `git push` then does what you would otherwise need to run `git push -u origin HEAD` for.